# Does using Haskell's (++) operator to append to list cause multiple list traversals?

Tags: list, haskell, optimization, time-complexity

Does appending to a Haskell list with `(++)` cause lists to be traversed multiple times?

I tried a simple experiment in GHCI.

The first run:

```
$ ghci
GHCi, version 7.8.4: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude> let t = replicate 9999999 'a' ++ ['x'] in last t
'x'
(0.33 secs, 1129265584 bytes)
```

The second run:

```
$ ghci
GHCi, version 7.8.4: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude> let t = replicate 9999999 'a' in last t
'a'
(0.18 secs, 568843816 bytes)
```

The only difference is the `++ ['x']` to append a last element to a list. It causes the runtime to increase from .18s to .33s, and the memory to increase from 568MB to 1.12GB.

So it seems that indeed it does cause multiple traversals. Can someone confirm on more theoretical grounds?

Comment: Notice that 1.12GB is about twice as large as 568MB, when you do `++['x']`, GHC will traverse the list `replicate 9999999 'a'` to do the concat, and then it will traverse again to do `last`.  Keep in mind that enabling optimizations when compiling could likely make this go away.  Profiling code in GHCi is not terribly accurate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd like to talk a bit about what happens when we enable optimizations, because it can transform the performance characteristics of the program pretty radically. I'll be looking at the [Core](http://www.haskellforall.com/2012/10/hello-core.html) output produced by `ghc -O2 Main.hs -ddump-simpl -dsuppress-all`. Also, I run the compiled programs with `+RTS -s` to get info about memory usage and running time.

With **GHC 7.8.4** the two versions of the code run in the same amount of time and with the same amount of heap allocation. That's because `replicate 9999999 'a'` and `++ ['x']` is replaced with a `genlist 9999999`, where `genlist` looks like the following (not exactly the same, as I employ liberal translation from the original Core):

```
genlist :: Int -> [Char]
genlist n | n <= 1 = "ax"
          | otherwise = 'a' : genList (n - 1)
```

Since we do generation and concatenation in a single step, we allocate each list cell just once.

With **GHC 7.10.1**, we get fancy new optimizations for list processing. Now both of our programs allocate about as much memory as a `print $ "Hello World"` program (about 52 Kb on my machine). This is because we skip the list creation entirely. Now `last` is fused away too; we instead get a call `getlast 9999999`, with `getlast` being:

```
getlast :: Int -> Char
getlast 1 = 'x'
getlast n = getlast (n - 1)
```

In the executable we'll have a small machine code loop that counts down from `9999999` to `1`. GHC is not quite smart enough to skip all computation and go straight to returning `'x'`, but it does a good job nevertheless, and in the end it gives us something rather different to the original code.

Comment: With `-fllvm` the LLVM optimizer will remove that loop and the program will run in constant time. Useless, but neat.

Comment: We don't have LLVM support for GHC 7.10 as of now, though (or do we have?).

Comment: GHC 7.10 does support LLVM but only version 3.5. Unfortunately there's no warning telling you to use 3.5 if you try to use an older version (oops). GHC HEAD requires version 3.6 and in the future we plan to bundle a version of LLVM with GHC because it has historically been difficult to support (and test) multiple LLVM versions in the LLVM backend.

Comment: I always add `-dno-suppress-type-signatures` to my `-dsuppress-all`—it tends to make it much easier to see what's what, especially when the names get munged.

Comment: "With GHC 7.10.1, we get fancy new optimizations for list processing."  Is there somewhere I can go and read about these? I can's sport any item in the [7.10.1 release notes](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.10.1/docs/html/users_guide/release-7-10-1.html) that sounds like that, but maybe it's an optimization in `base` and not the compiler proper?

Comment: @LuisCasillas see [this paper](http://www.joachim-breitner.de/publications/CallArity-TFP.pdf).

Comment: @AndrásKovács Thanks. I tried to do what you did, but I can't seem to see `genlist`? Which part of the output [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6097416eecdfc62d696f) is the `genlist` function?

Comment: @Ana it's not called "genlist" in the Core, it's "main_xs" here as I see. I translated to more illustrative names in the answer. Usually we get random mangled names ("main_xs" is relatively readable by comparison).

Comment: @AndrásKovács I see it now! Thanks very much. Core is not easy to read.

Answer (score 6):

You can't conclude from these numbers whether the first run does two traversals, or one traversal in which each step takes more time and allocates more memory than the single traversal in the second run.

In fact, it's the latter that is happening here. You can think of the two evaluations like this:

- in the second expression `let t = replicate 9999999 'a' in last t`, in each step but the last one, `last` evaluates its argument, which causes `replicate` to allocate a cons cell and decrement a counter, and then the cons cell is consumed by `last`.
- in the first expression `let t = replicate 9999999 'a' ++ ['x'] in last t`, in each step but the last one, `last` evaluates its argument, which causes `(++)` to evaluate its first argument, which causes `replicate` to allocate a cons cell and decrement a counter, and then that cons cell is consumed by `(++)` and `(++)` allocates a new cons cell, and then that new cons cell is consumed by `last`.

So the first expression is still a single traversal, it's just one that does more work per step.

Now if you wanted to you could divide up all this work into "the work done by `last`" and "the work done by `(++)`" and call those two "traversals"; and that can be a useful approach for understanding the total amount of work done by your program. But due to Haskell's laziness, the two "traversals" are really interleaved as described above, so most people would say that the list is traversed just once.

Comment: You *can* tell that from the given numbers! If it were doing two traverals, garbage collection (and probably cache misses) would make the appending version much worse than twice as slow as the simple one.

Comment: (It's slightly off-topic, but I found out that GHC 7.10 somehow leaks space on -O0 with the example program, while GHC 7.8.4 does fine. The issue remains when I use the old definition of `replicate` from base-4.7.0.2 instead of the new one in base-4.8)

Comment: @dfeuer: heh, true enough in practice I suppose. But at any rate one can't conclude that there are two separate traversals happening like the OP suggested.

Comment: @AndrásKovács, that's troubling. Have you filed a bug report yet? I don't know if I'll have time to investigate this week.

Comment: @AndrásKovács, actually, I'm pretty sure I know why: the new definition of `last` uses `foldl`, which is now defined as `foldr (\(v::a) (fn::b->b) -> oneShot (\(z::b) -> fn (k z v))) (id :: b -> b) xs z0`, which probably stinks without optimization.